# What it the best structure for an openapi api-first gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, openapi-generator

How would you structure a Gradle project which should do the following?

- generate a spring boot skeleton for an openapi REST api spec.
- building a spring boot application which implents this skeleton. This will be the server application.
- generate a Java client from the same openapi spec, which is published to something like artifactory and can be used by other projects.

The challenges I see here are:

- Where to put the `openapi.yml`. In a separate gradle subproject which only provided the openapi spec as a resource and which is a dependency for a server and client subproject? How can I refer to the spec in the `inputSpec` property of the openApiGenerate task?
- There have to be two openapi generator tasks, one for the server code and one for the client. Should is be in the same gradle subproject? How is this possible technically? To me, this seems wrong anyway, since you actively have to define which packages to include when building the client jar. And the server code would also contain the client classes by default.